# A SqlParameter with ParameterName '@0' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection

Tags: c#, sql, parameters

See code snippet, I can't seem to find my error, any help would be appreciated. The exception is on the first parameter add, (@0).

> Error: An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@0' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection

Code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConString))
{
    SqlCommand insertQuery = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO user_table (Username, Password, Name, Surname, DOB) VALUES ( @0, @1, @2, @3, @4 )", conn);

    insertQuery.Parameters["@0"].Value = edtUsername.Text;
    insertQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", edtPassword.Text);
    insertQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", edtName.Text);
    insertQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", edtSurname.Text);
    insertQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", dateTimePicker.Text);

    conn.Open();
    insertQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
} // using conn
```

Comment: Why are you adding it differently from the others? Can't you add it the same way you added the other parameters - (insertQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue)

Comment: I just added both ways to show I tried both ways I know of, not one of them works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems with this code:

1. You are not adding the parameter `@0`, you try to set its value before you added it.
2. [Don't use `AddWithValue`. Use `Add` instead.](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)
3. Don't use `@0`, `@1`, etc as parameter names, instead use meaningful names. It's not that important when there are only 5 parameters but using meaningful names everywhere is a good habit.
4. Don't pass dates as strings, pass them as instances of `DateTime`. This will save you a lot of trouble messing around with formats.
5. [Don't store plain text password in the database.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/) Use a hashing algorithm with salt.
6. SqlCommand is an IDisposable too.

A better code would be something like this:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConString))
{
    using(var insertQuery = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO user_table (Username, Password, Name, Surname, DOB) VALUES ( @Username, @Password, @Name, @Surname, @DOB)", conn))
    {
        // I'm assuming nvarchar as the data type, change it if needed....
        insertQuery.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = edtUsername.Text;
        // uniqueSalt can be stored as plain text in the database, but should be unique for each password.
        insertQuery.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = HashPassword(edtPassword.Text, uniqueSalt); 
        insertQuery.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = edtName.Text;
        insertQuery.Parameters.Add("@Surname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = edtSurname.Text;
        insertQuery.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker.Value;
        conn.Open();
        insertQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
} 

string HashPassword(string password, string salt)
{
    // TODO: Implement hashing with salt
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but for now I just want to get the insert query working, see this [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/SX4xh), even using the 'add' is not adding the parameters to the query

Comment: Just replaced my code with yours, works 100%, 'using var insertQuery = new sqlCommand() {}' seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad to help :-)